# java: Zip file size in target folder is bigger than original size in resources, won't unzip

Tags: java, maven, zip, target

I have a zip file of 672 bytes in the main/resources of my java project.

However when the project builds, the same file in target/classes in now a zip file of 1.10 KB.

When my code tried to unzip it, I get the error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
```

I think that the problem comes from the fact that the file is bigger in the target problem, because I have had other projects where I used my unZip function without any problem.
I have no idea what is making this and how to solve it?
Also not sure what info you need to help me? I am using Spring and Maven, and the JDK 1.8.0_45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from a combination of following settings in your `pom.xml`

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

this instructs maven to replace variables in the resources files (see: [Maven Resources Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)).

As you also instruct Maven to write the resources files encoded in UTF-8 (see: [Maven Resources encoding](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html)).

```
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
```

the ZIP file (which is a binary file) will be writen in UTF-8 encoding, which garbles the content.

If you would have used LATIN-1 as encoding it would work

```
<encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
```

Depending on your own answer. As it seems that you neither use the encoding as UTF-8 in the resources files nor the filtering of variables, removing both the resources plugin and the filtering instruction was the solution for you.

**edit** If for some reason you cannot use this encoding you can exclude files based on their extension from filtering.

```
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
...
<configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <escapeString>\</escapeString>
    ...
    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>zip</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are right, with the encoding to ASCII the files have the same size. However I get instead: `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
 at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)`, do you know why?

Comment: It works if I use the encoding `ISO-8859-1`! Thanks :)

Comment: @George Seems I had only luck. You can exclude some files from filtering. See my updated anser. Will also include your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting this piece of code in my pom.xml file did the trick:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <escapeString>\</escapeString>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Now the zip files has the same size in the target folder and can be unzip.

Problem solved, but I don't really understand what happened there...!

Answer (score 0):

When i building the jar using command "mvn clean package or install". I encountered this issue. "invalid code lengths set" and compilation error
 I struggled with weird issue. I tried all the suggested solution in POM.xml.

**But Finally I removed the .m2 directory which size was more than 3 GB.[Its tedious and** weird solution].
**But It is perfectly working for me.**